# How to pass array data in model from controller in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

> Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to
>   function Articlesmodel::update_article(), 0 passed

**Here is my model**

### articlesmodel.php

```
function update_article($article_id,Array $article){

    return $this->db
            ->where('id',$article_id)
            ->update('articles',$article);
}
```

**Here is my Controller**

### admin.php

```
function update_article(){
    print_r($this->input->post());
    $this->load->model('articlesmodel');
    $update_articles=$this->articlesmodel->update_article();
    if($update_articles){

    }
}
```

Comment: `update_article($article_id,Array $article)` takes 2 arguments. You wrote `update_article()`, which gives 0 arguments. Why is that hard to understand?

Comment: pass `$article_id` and `$article` like this : `$update_articles=$this->articlesmodel->update_article($article_id,$article);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i solved my problem. Here was the problem in, **$post** i can't pass the this variable in function under below `$post=$this->input->post();`

```
`

**before fixing  error the was problem here**

`function update_article(){
        print_r($this->input->post());
        $this->load->model('articlesmodel');
        $update_articles=$this->articlesmodel->update_article();
        if($update_articles){

        }

}`
```

**After fixing error the code is.**

```
function update_article(){
                       print_r($this->input->post());
                       $this->load->model('articlesmodel');
                       $post=$this->input->post();
                      $update_articles=$this->articlesmodel->update_article($article_id,$post);
                       if($update_articles){

                       }
                   }
```

i didn't declear the **$post** in controler and not pass **2 param** in Controller `$update_articles`

After `$update_articles=$this->articlesmodel->update_article($article_id,$post)`

Before `$update_articles=$this->articlesmodel->update_article();`

Answer (score 1):

In your model you are accepting 2 params but you're not sending them from controller. Just send the 2 params from controller to model and it will work fine

***In Model***

```
update_article($article_id,Array $article)
```

***in Controller***

```
update_article($MISSING,$MISSING)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function update_article($article_id,$article){

        $this->db->trans_start();
        $this->db->where('id', $article_id);
        $this->db->update('articles', $article);
        $this->db->trans_complete();
        return TRUE;
}
```

hope this will help you